# Restore deleted photos

Tags: photos, recovery-tool

I have accidently deleted some photos from my Lumia 640, and would like to bring them back. The photos were stored on the microSD card, but I don't have a microSD card reader for my laptop, so I have to connect the phone with an usb cable. 
That way, I can see the phone listed as "Windows Phone" in MyComputer, but it has no drive letter, so that no recovery program can find it.
Is there anything I can do to save the pictures?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is to get a (usb) card reader and try to run the recovery tool then - this worked for me. It won't work connecting your phone directly, though.

In the meantime I'd recommend removing the SD card from your phone to prevent your photos from being overwritten with different data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the OneDrive applications. If you didn't disable it, all the photos you've taken will be stored there.

Comment: thx for the suggestion, but my phone was offline :)